# Creating a logo with style similar to Flask's

Tags: python, vector-graphics, graphic-design

I'm wondering what are the options for creating a logo in a style similar to [`Flask`](http://flask.pocoo.org/), the [`requests`](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/) library and some Flask extensions, like:

- [`flask-restless`](https://flask-restless.readthedocs.org/en/latest/)
- [`flask-script`](http://flask-script.readthedocs.org/en/latest/)
- [`frozen-flask`](http://pythonhosted.org/Frozen-Flask/)

I've googled a lot without any success so far. I'm aware this could be created via Photoshop or some other graphic design software, but I'm trying to find out if there is some sort of tool that, for example, takes a base image and renders one like the logos on the above links.

I'm betting I'm gonna have to create my own "by hand" with graphic design software, but I want to exhaust the options first.

Any help will be greatly appreciated! Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could get a good starting point by using [Gimp](http://gimp.org) and the [G'MIC](http://gmic.eu/) plugin, take a photo of something related to your product and crop then use the G'MIC engrave filter, add your text and you are away.

E.g.: [image: PySol] using the above process can give [image: Engraved] *- not bad for 4 mins.*

***Note:** [GMIC](http://gmic.eu/) is also available for command line use and [ImageMagick](http://imagemagick.org/) can be used from the command line to add text so you could probably come up with a semi-automatic process.*